# How to install the Google Cloud SDK in a Docker Image?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How can I build a Docker container with [Google's Cloud Command Line Tool/SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/#Quick_Start)?

The script at the url https://sdk.cloud.google.com appears to require user input so doesn't work in a docker file.

Answer (score 90):

Adding the following to my Docker file appears to work.

```
# Downloading gcloud package
RUN curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz > /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz

# Installing the package
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud \
  && tar -C /usr/local/gcloud -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz \
  && /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh

# Adding the package path to local
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin
```

Comment: I would add for convenience an ENV directive for the PATH environment variable:

ENV $PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin

Comment: I think you need `ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin`

Comment: I think you now need /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --quiet (need to add quiet flag to avoid the manual step)

Comment: @Jeremy Hi I stumbled upon your answer as I am doing the same thing. Just wanted to know which base image you were using.

Comment: @Mustufain it's possible by using alpine: `FROM alpine:3.6`

Comment: In addition to the above I needed `RUN gcloud components install kubectl` - after the ENV PATH line.

Comment: I can't win on this, all I ever get in any alpine image trying any form of install is executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud   && tar -C /usr/local/gcloud -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz   && /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh]: exit code: 127

Comment: I run this after installation `export PATH="/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 52):

Use this one-liner in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

source: 
https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/installation/google/

Comment: Worked with `ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin`

Comment: The install location will be different for various installs but the theory here is sound

Comment: With `ENV CLOUDSDK_INSTALL_DIR /usr/local/gcloud/` you can define where it should be installed.
source:  https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash

Comment: On `debian:stretch` I also had to add `ENV PATH $PATH:/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin` so this can work.

Comment: Link to docker seems to be gone. Found another reference at https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9497473

Comment: This is installed in `/app/home` by default, so I needed to do `ENV PATH $PATH:/home/app/google-cloud-sdk/bin` to get it working. (I tried to specify `ENV CLOUD_SDK_INSTALL_DIR /usr/local/gcloud/` so I could add it to that to the PATH, but got a permission denied when building the image.)

Answer (score 32):

Doing it with alpine:

```
 FROM alpine:3.6

 RUN apk add --update \
 python \
 curl \
 which \
 bash

 RUN curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash

 ENV PATH $PATH:/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin
```

Comment: This almost works.  I get this today:  ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 27, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk import gcloud_main
  File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud_main.py", line 37, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.command_lib.util.apis import yaml_command_translator
  File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/util/apis/yaml_command_translator.py", line 241
    if self.spec.async:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: To get around that I had to install python version 2 first, and then remove it and install python 3.  ```RUN apk --no-cache add python2
RUN curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
RUN apk del python2 && apk --no-cache add python3
```

Comment: Obviously, you can't _use_ gcloud without python2 installed.  I only needed it for some container setup, and removed python2 after I was done with it.  (sorry I didn't make that clear in my earlier comment)

Comment: Update here, as of Nov 16, 2021 gcloud supports python 2.7.x or 3.5-3.8. You'll have issues with the latest versions of python until they update there supported versions but you don't have to set up python2 anymore

Comment: This is the actual answer, it installed but I have no single clue where it actually installed it to.

Comment: It doesn't install it anywhere, it disappears.

Comment: For `alpine:3.15` you need to replace `python` to `python3`

Comment: The "For alpine:3.15 you need to replace python to python3" comment is valid for above versions to, and at the time of writing these lines.

Answer (score 28):

```
RUN curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com > /tmp/gcl && bash /tmp/gcl --install-dir=~/gcloud --disable-prompts
```

This will download the google cloud sdk installer into `/tmp/gcl`, and run it with the parameters as follows:

- **--install-dir=~/gcloud**: Extract the binaries into folder gcloud in home folder. Change this to wherever you want, for example `/usr/local/bin`
- **--disable-prompts**: Don't show any prompts while installing (headless)

Comment: Please explain the code you just added, to improve your answer. Avoid posting code only answers or questions...

Comment: This is the correct response. Be sure you have `tar` and `which` installed in your docker container.

Comment: Looks like there is a stray backtick at the end of the command, should be edited.

Comment: @hallvors fixed

Comment: Feel free to add `gcloud` to your `PATH` with `ENV PATH $PATH:~/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin`

Comment: This will not work in a docker-in-docker container, as python3, curl, which and bash will missing, hence adi biton's hencer.

Answer (score 18):

To install gcloud inside a docker container please follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb).

Basically you need to run

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl gnupg && \
    echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && \
    curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg  add - && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install google-cloud-sdk -y
```

inside your dockerfile. It's important you are user `ROOT` when you run this command, so it may necessary to add `USER root` before the previous command.

Comment: known issue with gpg-key not sure about what is causing it https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/known-issues#ubuntu-systems

Comment: step 3 of this doc details how to handle the key ring issue: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb

Answer (score 11):

As an alternative, you could use the docker image provided by google namely `google/cloud-sdk`.  https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/

Comment: ...or copy from its dockerfile

Comment: @JohnWhite this might be an obvious question, but where would one find the dockerfile ? I found this : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile from an issue link in https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/ , i'm not sure if there's a "nicer" way to find this in general though

Comment: @baxx Yeah, I found their official image here https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/dockerfile/ and it's not the best way, but it should work.

Comment: ohhh you can just add `dockerfile` to the url, nice :)

Answer (score 7):

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum update -y && yum install -y \
                    curl \
                    which && \
    yum clean all

RUN curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash

ENV PATH $PATH:/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin
```

Build:

```
docker build . -t google-cloud-sdk
```

Then run `gcloud`:

```
docker run --rm \
--volume $(pwd)/assets/root/.config:/root/.config \
google-cloud-sdk gcloud
```

...or run `gsutil`:

```
docker run --rm \
--volume $(pwd)/assets/root/.config:/root/.config \
google-cloud-sdk gsutil
```

The local `assets` folder will contain the configuration.

Answer (score 4):

```
apk upgrade --update-cache --available && \
apk add openssl && \
apk add curl python3 py-crcmod bash libc6-compat && \
rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash > /dev/null
export PATH=$PATH:/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin
gcloud components update kubectl
```

Comment: don't forget to add `--install-dir=/root --disable-prompts` params to bash

Answer (score 4):

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash -s -- --disable-prompts
```

and export env
works for me

Answer (score 3):

I was using Python Alpine image `python:3.8.6-alpine3.12` as base and this worked for me:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

RUN wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-327.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz \
    -O /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz | bash

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud \
    && tar -C /usr/local/gcloud -xvzf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz \
    && /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh -q

ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin
```

- After building and running the image, you can check if `google-cloud-sdk` is installed by running `docker exec -i -t <container_id> /bin/bash` and running this:

```sh
bash-5.0# gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 327.0.0
bq 2.0.64
core 2021.02.05
gsutil 4.58
bash-5.0# gsutil --version
gsutil version: 4.58
```

If you want a specific version of `google-cloud-sdk`, you can visit https://storage.cloud.google.com/cloud-sdk-release

Answer (score 3):

You can use multi-stage builds to make this simpler and more efficient than solutions using `curl`.

```
FROM bitnami/google-cloud-sdk:0.392.0 as gcloud

FROM base-image-for-production:tag

# Do what you need to configure your production image

COPY --from=gcloud /opt/bitnami/google-cloud-sdk/ /google-cloud-sdk
```

Answer (score 2):

This work for me.

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install -y python && \
    curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash

ENV PATH $PATH:/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this working with Ubuntu 18.04 using:

```
RUN apt-get install -y curl && curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin"
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the python 3 requirement

Answer (score 1):

An example using debian as the base image:

```
FROM debian:stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https gnupg curl lsb-release

RUN export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)" && \
  echo "cloud SDK repo: $CLOUD_SDK_REPO" && \
  echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && \
  curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - && \
  apt-get update -y && apt-get install google-cloud-sdk -y
```

Answer (score 0):

I used most of these examples in some form (thanks @KJoe), but I had to do several other things to setup everything so `gcloud` would work in the environment.  Note that it is preferable to limit the number of lines (it limits layers needed to pull)

Here's a more complete example of Dockerfile with `gcloud` setup and extending a CircleCI image:

```
FROM circleci/ruby:2.4.1-jessie-node-browsers

# user is circleci in the FROM image, switch to root for system lib installation
USER root

ENV CCI /home/circleci
ENV GTMP /tmp/gcloud-install
ENV GSDK $CCI/google-cloud-sdk
ENV PATH="${GSDK}/bin:${PATH}"

# do all system lib installation in one-line to optimize layers
RUN curl -sSL https://sdk.cloud.google.com > $GTMP && bash $GTMP --install-dir=$CCI --disable-prompts \
  && rm -rf $GTMP \
  && chmod +x $GSDK/bin/* \
  \
  && chown -Rf circleci:circleci $CCI

# change back to the user in the FROM image
USER circleci

# setup gcloud specifics to your liking
RUN gcloud config set core/disable_usage_reporting true \
  && gcloud config set component_manager/disable_update_check true \
  && gcloud components install alpha beta kubectl --quiet
```

Answer (score 0):

My use case was to generate a google bearer token using the service account, so I wanted the docker container to install `gcloud` this is how my docker file looks like

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk
# Setting the default directory in container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# copies the app source code to the directory in container
COPY . /usr/src/app
CMD ["/bin/bash","/usr/src/app/token.sh"]
```

If you need to examine a container after it is built but that isn't running use `docker run --rm -it <container-build-id>  bash -il` and type in `gcloud --version` if installed correctly or not

Answer (score 0):

In Google documentation you can see the best practice
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install-sdk
search on the page for "Docker Tip"

eg debian use:

```
RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg  add - && apt-get update -y && apt-get install google-cloud-cli -y
```

Comment: This one command adds 884MB, starting `FROM python:3.10-slim-bookworm`. Any tips for making it smaller?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in getting the gcloud CLI available, add this to your Dockerfile:

```
# Downloading gcloud package
RUN curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-cli-409.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz > /tmp/google-cloud-cli.tar.gz

# Installing the gcloud cli
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud \
  && tar -xf /tmp/google-cloud-cli.tar.gz \
  && ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --quiet
```