# Set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` for AppEngine Flexible Environment instances

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My application requires the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to be set. However, when SSH'ing into my Google AppEngine Flexible Environment instance and running `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, I'm seeing that the environment variable is not set.

I'm deploying via `gcloud app deploy --image-url "gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/$GITHUB_SHA"`. Is there anything else I need to do ensure that the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is properly set on the newly running instance(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom runtime docker images are images not handled or modified by google, this means that GCloud is not available because when the images were built the sdk was not installed as is mentioned in this [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372328/how-to-install-the-google-cloud-sdk-in-a-docker-image), also the custom runtimes do not include any credential, only flexible (based on google runtimes) or standard instances include default credentials.

To fix this you need to [create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account) and add the permissions necessaries, after the creation of this account you need to generate the json credentials

To create the json credentials it is necessary to access to the [service accounts page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts)

Click on the 3 dots icon in the column actions in the row that matches with your service account, in the menu select `create key` in the modal select JSON and click on `CREATE` button.

This file needs to be added  to your docker image and you need to define  the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with the path of the credentials file.

For example by adding the environment variable on your `dockerfile`

```
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
```

With this steps, your App Engine instances based on a custom runtime will be able to use the credentials linked to the service account to use other GCP products or services

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/service-account):

> After you create an App Engine application, the App Engine default
> service account is created and used as the identity of the App Engine
> service. The App Engine default service account is associated with
> your Cloud project and executes tasks on behalf of your apps running
> in App Engine.
>
> By default, the App Engine default service account has the Editor role
> in the project.

Therefore you do not need to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for your application running on App Engine Flex.

Comment: Yes, that's what I read as well, but running `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in an instance shows that the environment variable isn't set for some reason (and `gcloud` isn't available as well)

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah are you using a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a custom runtime with a docker image