# Modify Google Cloud Project resources from a Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

For instance, I want to run the following gcloud CLI command,

```
gcloud run services delete [SERVICE]
```

But, from a triggered Google Cloud Function.

I've looked in a few places and have found a few similar things,

- https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Infrastructure-Compute-Storage/Automatic-Resource-Deletion/m-p/172865
- https://github.com/PolideaInternal/cats-love-money
- [Create a Google function from a Google cloud function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60609309/create-a-google-function-from-a-google-cloud-function)

But, I find them a bit tricky to follow and/or replicate.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Cloud CLI is a Python program. That means a lot of dependencies and a requirement for a shell and OS environment. Cloud Functions does not provide either.

A better option for running the CLI is Cloud Run. This provides the additional benefit of being able to test the Cloud Run container locally. You will need to wrap the CLI with an HTTP server responding to HTTP requests which then execute the CLI.

However, most CLI commands can be easily duplicated with the Python SDKs and/or direct REST API calls which are supported by Cloud Functions. This will require a solid understanding of the services, APIs, and language.

Comment: @John_Hanley, using REST seems best for me because I do mostly frontend web development, however, Cloud Run sounds interesting. I have 2 questions: ****Q1: Assuming I'd have to fork processes to make gcloud calls in Cloud Run, do Cloud Run instances have gcloud available as a command by default ? Or, how does one get gcloud on a Cloud Run instance? What about gcloud login/auth?  ****Q2: Do you know where one can find the documentation for the gcloud python SDK or gcloud REST API? Or, what is the name of the Google SDK/API used to invoke gcloud commands so that I can search for it? Thanks!

Comment: @Tom - Do not ask new questions in comments. Create a new question. Your questions need more space than comments allow. 1) Cloud Run runs Docker containers. You create the container with whatever you want inside. https://stackoverflow.com/q/28372328/8016720 2) https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference